# Build autocorrelation matrix in Python

Tags: programming

I am interested to build the following matrices in Python $B_{tt'} = e^{−|t − t'|/\tau }$ and $B_{tt'} = b^{|t−t'|}$, where $t,t' = 1, 2, \ldots , T$ for some fixed $T$, $|b| < 1$, and $\tau > 0$. Could someone please demonstrate to me a Pythonic way to build these matrices? Thanks!

Comment: What are $t$, $t'$ and $\tau$?

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for your response! I have added more clarity into the question.

Comment: Much clearer now, thanks. I'm not sure what is _most_ Pythonic though, hopefully someone else can help. You want a `numpy.matrix` right?

Comment: Yes, I'd like a `numpy.matrix` as an output!

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(1,T,T)

t1,t2 = np.meshgrid(t,t)

Btt = np.exp(-np.abs(t1-t2)/tau) #Btt = b**np.abs(t1-t2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Below will do the trick without using `np.matrix`.  The matrix class isn't used much.  See docs [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html?highlight=numpy%20matrix#numpy.matrix).  They recommend avoiding it and using arrays instead.

Below are 2 separate approaches.  The first function is convolutional, the second is statistical (normalized on [-1,1] interval).  The input `x` should be a 1-d array. Both functions return a 1-d array.

```
import numpy as np 

def autocorr_conv(x):
    result = np.correlate(x, x, mode='full')
    return result[result.size // 2:]



def autocorr_stat(x):
    return np.array([1]+[np.corrcoef(x[:-i], x[i:])[0,1] for i in range(1, len(x)-1])
```